# Cloud foundry not compatible with IE?

Tags: javascript, html, css, cloud-foundry

When I run my application locally, the UI looks perfectly fine on *any browser*.
When I deploy my application onto cloud foundry, it gives me a link to view the application. The UI looks fine on Mozilla firefox and google chrome. But on IE it looks distorted and messed up.
As I said previously when I ran my application locally my UI looks fine on IE, Only when I deployed it on CF and view it. It looks messed up.

**Running Locally**
(Chrome, Mozilla, and IE. Looks like this)

(Chome and Mozilla also looks like his after deployed on CF)

[image: local]

**Deployed on CF** (Only IE looks like this)

[image: IE ON CF]

It looks like my css, javascript, ajs, all not working. I do have "!DOCTYPE html" specified on top of my html files.

**Extra Info on Project**

The project is written with Java, springboot and thymeleaf. I am deploying my application as a jar. "-cf push". I am currently using java_buildpack_offline

Comment: which buildpack are you using, how are you building and deploying your app? you're mussing all the information which might help to help you.

Comment: @LBA Provided the details requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My application was running on default emulation of IE7. I added the following code into my html script and I was able to retain my javascripts, css, etc...

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10"/>
```